# A set in the plane mapping elements with an inversion

Tags: geometry

We say a finite set $\displaystyle \mathcal{S}$ of points in the plane is $very$ if for every $\displaystyle X\in \mathcal{S}$ there exists an inversion $\displaystyle \mathcal{I}$ with center $\displaystyle X$ mapping every point except $X$ in $\displaystyle \mathcal{S}$ to another point in $\displaystyle \mathcal{S}$(possibly the same point).

- Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}$, prove that any line segment $\overline{AB}$ contains a unique $very$ set $\mathcal{S}$ which has size $n$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{S}$.
- Find the largest possible very set not contained in any line.

Can someone help me? This is a problem given to me by my teacher. Thanks.

Comment: I have to say, that must be the *very* worst mathematical terminology I have ever heard.

Comment: Could you tell me the areas I should edit? I am sorry this problem is actually from the training exam of USA IMO Team, and this is the version of it my teacher had. Sorry about all the problem I caused you.